# How to collect the return value of a function (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, function, parameters

**Goal:**
I want to collect the return value of a function.

**Question:**
How can I call the 'test' function to collect the return variable 'name' without passing through a parameter?

Is there a way to collect a variable(values) from functions with agruments(parameters) without passing through a parameter?

I have provided an example:

```
let userName = "Jake"
let userInfo = test(name: userName)

    func test(name: String) -> String {

        return name
    }

    // function call
    // Goal: I want to retrieve the function return value without passing a parameter
    let newUser = test()
```

Does the function 'test' return value have to be stored to retrieve it?
I want to retrieve the 'userName' Jake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `return` like below,

```
let userName = "Jake" //Global variable of the class
let userInfo = test() //Jake

func test() -> String { //single - element tuple will don't have label for return.

   return self.userName
}
```

If you like to `return` with `labels` then you need `tow or more` return values like below,

```
   func test() -> (name:String,age:Int) {        
       return (self.userName,125)
    }
```

And access specific values by `test().name`